# Simple shadow detection method from single image

Tags: computer-vision, shadow

Is there are any simple shadow detection method from single image?
For example convert to HSV split channels, make threshold on some channel or using some simple statistics of image pixels mean,stddev?

What are properties of shadow?
for example from [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20002/what-are-characteristics-of-shadows-in-an-image-given-an-outdoor-setting-from-an/):

> similar chromaticity but lower brightness
>
> saturation component of the shadow should be low

Comment: FINLAYSON, Graham D., et al. On the removal of shadows from images. *Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, IEEE Transactions on*, 2006, 28.1: 59-68. http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~mark/ftp/Pami06/pami06.pdf